# Distributing data read from GetMongo in a nifi cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a clustered nifi setup and we are running GetMongo processor with the Primary mode on, so that duplicate data is not fetched. This seems to be working fine. However once I have this data I want the following processes in the chain to run on a cluster, as in parallel processing to be done on this data which has been fetched. Somehow this is not happening. So my question is below assuming GetMongo has fetched 30000 records and they are in the queue:

1) How do I check whether a processor is running its process on a single node or on all nodes. The config has been set to all nodes, but when the processor is running I see it displays 1 in the top right corner.

2) If one processor has been set to run only on primary node, do all other processors in the flow also run on Primary mode?

Example:

[image]

In the screenshot above, my getmongo is running in primary node, how do I make sure that the execute script processor runs in parallel on all 3 nifi nodes. As of now if I check the view status history in the executescript process I see data flowing only through the primary node.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. When you mark the source processor to run only the `Primary Node`, all the subsequent steps will only happen on that node alone since the data is residing only that node (primary node), even when you have the NiFi in a clustered mode. To make it work the way you want, you can follow either of the following two approaches:

**Approach #1 : Comibination of RPG and Site-To-Site**

Here your flow will look like this:

- Create an Input Port on the Root Group (the very top level of the NiFi canvas)
- Make `GetMongo` run only on Primary Node.
- Connect the `success` relationship of the processor to a Remote Processor Group (RPG). This RPG can be configured with the cluster details itself and configure it to connect to the port you added in step #1.
- From the input port, connect it to your processing logic.

[image]

[image]

**Useful Links:**

- https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/

This is cumbersome and would make your flow very complex but this how it has to be done, till NiFi 1.8. With NiFi 1.8, you can use the following approach.

**Approach #2 : Load-Balanced Connections (Apache NiFi 1.8+)**

Apache NiFi had a new release - 1.8, a week ago. With this release, there is a new feature (a long time coming and very much desired one) was introduced. It is called Load-Balanced Connections.

In this approach, you can simply ignore the RPG/Site-To-Site combination and rather do the following:

- Connect the output of your source processor, in this case `GetMongo` with the subsequent processors.
- Right click the `success` relationship of the source processor.
- Click `configure`
- Go to `Settings` tab
- Set the `Load Balance Strategy` to the desired one, preferably `Roudd robin` in your case.

[image]

[image]

**Useful Links:**

- https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster
- https://pierrevillard.com/2018/10/29/nifi-1-8-revolutionizing-the-list-fetch-pattern-and-more/